# CGFloat *f= accelerometer.x;

Tags: iphone

I have used this but it is not working?How can i store accelerometer.x value in a int or float or CGFloat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGFloat` is just a typedef for `float`, so it is not an object. Try `CGFloat f= accelerometer.x;`